# How to implement recursive DFS in Python efficiently?

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search

I am trying to implement recursive DFS in Python. My attempt is:

```
def dfs_recursive(graph, vertex, path=[]):
    path += [vertex]

    for neighbor in graph[vertex]:
        # print(neighbor)
        if neighbor not in path:  # inefficient line
            path = dfs_recursive(graph, neighbor, path)

    return path


adjacency_matrix = {"s": ["a", "c", "d"], "c": ["e", "b"],
                    "b": ["d"], "d": ["c"], "e": ["s"], "a": []}
```

Unfortunately, the line `if neighbor not in path` is very inefficient and not what I am supposed to do. I would like the output to be the nodes that are visited in order, but without duplicates. So in this case:

```
['s', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'b', 'd']
```

How can I output the nodes that are visited in DFS order but without duplicates efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `OrderedDict` for your `path` variable. That will make the `in` operator run in constant time. Then to turn that into a list, just get the keys from that dict, which are guaranteed to be in insertion-order.

I would also put the recursive part of the overall function into a separate function. That way you don't have to pass `path` as an argument in each recursive call:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def dfs_recursive(graph, vertex):
    path = OrderedDict()

    def recur(vertex):
        path[vertex] = True
        for neighbor in graph[vertex]:
            if neighbor not in path:
                recur(neighbor)

    recur(vertex)
    return list(path.keys())

adjacency_matrix = {"s": ["a", "c", "d"], "c": ["e", "b"],
                    "b": ["d"], "d": ["c"], "e": ["s"], "a": []}

print(dfs_recursive(adjacency_matrix, "s"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `dict`:

```
def dfs_recursive(graph, vertex, path={}):
    path[vertex] = None

    for neighbor in graph[vertex]:
        if neighbor not in path:
            dfs_recursive(graph, neighbor)

    return path

adjacency_matrix = {"s": ["a", "c", "d"], "c": ["e", "b"],
                    "b": ["d"], "d": ["c"], "e": ["s"], "a": []}

print(*dfs_recursive(adjacency_matrix, "s"))
```

Output:

```
s a c e b d
```

Comment: I don't that your code gives the promised output. path is never updated.

Comment: @fomin Have you tried it? It's updated in the first line of the function. Just like in yours.

Comment: Ah yes but it outputs "b d s c e a" . See https://imgur.com/a/AFzpsE3

Comment: @fomin Then you must be using an outdated Python version. What version are you using?

Comment: Python 3.5.2 . It would be great to have a version that worked with all Python 3.5+.

Comment: How come set prints the keys ordered? set is supposed to be unordered. Interesting.

Comment: @SomeDude I'm using a dict, not a set.

Comment: @SomeDude At some point all dicts became ordered dicts in Python. But this is after 3.5.2 it seems.

Comment: @fomin it became order preserving in 3.6 where it was considered an implementation detail, and in 3.7 it became part of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def dfs_recursive(graph, vertex, dic, path):

    dic[vertex] = 1;
    path += vertex
    for neighbor in graph[vertex]:

        if not neighbor in dic: 
           dfs_recursive(graph, neighbor, dic, path)



graph = {"s": ["a", "c", "d"], "c": ["e", "b"],
                    "b": ["d"], "d": ["c"], "e": ["s"], "a": []}

path = [];
dic = {}
dfs_recursive(graph,"s",dic,path);

print(path)
```

You need to have a dictionary for efficient lookups, if you want path you could add it to a different structure as shown above.

Comment: You don't need a dict in the first version, where a set gives you all you're using. And I'm pretty sure the second version isn't correct.

Comment: I would really like the same order as given by the adjacency lists.

Comment: Turns out I can't upvote an answer until I have 15 points. Sorry. But thank you for the answer.